# I can't boot into windows: error: unknown command 'drivemap'; invalid EFI file path

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I had Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu and all worked well. After a problem with my video configs I decided to unistall Ubuntu and I made a fatal mistake: deleted the Linux partition. After that I couldn't boot into windows. 
So, I decided reinstall Ubuntu at the same partition used before. 
But until now I'm unable to use the Microsoft OS. 
After trying any several ways to solve the problem, I installed boot-repair and get this error:

```
unknown command 'drivemap'
invalid EFI file path
```

Here is the boot-repair log file: 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/7832988/

My computer is an Asus Vivobook i7 64bits.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Use the Windows 8 disc, or the repair disc that came with your computer, boot from the disc and repair the Windows MBR.

Comment: I tried it. After get the command prompt, I typed these steps: bootrec.exe /fixmbr ==> bootrec.exe /fixboot ==> exit ==> restart ==> diskpart ==> list disk ==> select disk 1 ==> list partition ==> select partition 0 ==> active ==> exit ==> restart. Everything remains the same. After Ubuntu reinstall the recovery disk doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Try this answer, [http://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on]. It also gives an option to fix the windows using a Ubuntu live CD. Sorry, thats the best I can give you, as using windows repair has always worked...